# What is the fastest Android SDK setup?

Tags: android, android-emulator

What is the best platform and setup for running Android SDK?  It is so slow that I cannot stay focused on it.

If I had any hardware resources at my disposal and cost wasn't an issue, what should I do?

Also, is there some sort of cloud SDK host that can provide a faster experience.  (Security isn't a concern.  Just need to debug web sites.)

Comment: Get the best CPU you can, with focus on single-thread performance. The emulator is painfully slow.

Comment: What do you mean by the "SDK is slow"? How can the SDK be slow? Do you mean eclipse? The emulator? Or what?

Comment: I mean the emulator.  I am not using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have really bad experiences with running on Mac software so, aside from special cases, I would avoid mac hardware (yes I know they are seperate things, but still).

In my experience a VMWare virutal unbuntu in OSX runs Eclipse/javaSDK faster then just directly in OSX, on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, my development machine is old and slow and Eclipse was killing it. I recently switched to [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html) and it is much faster. I suggest at least giving it a shot. It has really good support built in for the Android SDK including logcat.